# div's between header and footer vertical 100%

Tags: html, css

I have been looking for an answer to this question but have not found anything. I have searched stack overflow and other resources. The question has been asked before and I have tried each of them the answers.

How can I get the div's to take up 100% of the vertical distance between the header and footer?

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div class="page-wrap">
 <header>This is the header</header>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="left">Left</div>
   <div id="right">Right</div>
   <div id="main">Main</div>
 </div>
 </div>
<footer class="site-footer">
 I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

CSS

```
/* * {
margin: 0;
} */
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}
.page-wrap {
min-height: 100%;
/* equal to footer height */
margin-bottom: -80px;
}
.page-wrap:after {
content: "";
display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
 height: 80px;
 }
.site-footer {
background: #265a88;
}

#left{
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 background-color: black;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
 border: black dash;
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 min-height:100%;
 overflow: scroll;

 }

 #right{
  min-height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  width: 20%;

  }

  #main{
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  border: black dash;
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  max-height:100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  }

  header{
  background-color: #265a88;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the dimensions of container as such:

```
#container{
   height: 100%
   width: 100%
   position: absolute;
}
```

However, in your case, you will have to set the height of the container so that it does not overflow and go over the footer.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a child element to take 100% of the parent's height, the parent must have a set height (ie can't be a percent). This applies to all child elements besides the `body` tag, who's parent is `html`, and `html` set to 100% does provide a set pixel height for child elements. The easiest workaround for this is to use some javascript to calculate the height of a given parent element, and then set the child element accordingly. I am not aware of any pure css solution, that doesn't require some fiddling with properties such as line-height. As far as I know, this is a very common issue for web developers, and one which really depends on your flexibility of technology used and how *hacked* you want your css to look.